# Disable button when width == 0 of left == -1000

Tags: jquery, button, slide

I really dont get this. I want to make div slides to left but when they reach a certain point the button must be disabled. Same goes for the right button.

This is my script code

```
$("#Next").click(function(){ 
$("#div").animate({"left": "-=800px"}, "slow");
});

$("#button-Prev").click(function(){ 
$("#div").animate({"left": "+=800px"}, "slow");
});

$(document).ready(function(){ 
var b = $("#div").css left;
    if (b > 0) {
        button active
    }
    else if(b == 0){
        //button disabled
    }

});

</script>
```

Comment: Do you expect this code to work right now? There isn't anything in there to disable a button. You haven't shown any markup, either. How about an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: No instead of disabeling the button I want height to go to 0px So it doesnt need to disable. But i will make a SSCCE. I'm sorry for that one very new to this.

Comment: Then you should **really** change the wording of the title and the question to ***say what you mean.***

Answer (score 1):

Animate has a callback parameter where you can specify a function to be executed when the animation completes, thats when you have to check and disable the buttons:

```
$("#inside").animate({"left": "-=800px"}, "slow", function() {
  if (this.style.left == 0) { $(this).disable() }
})
```

Comment: Was going to post this, although I'm unsure exactly which button the OP wants to disable to to lack of clear information. +1 anyway for the best method.

Comment: Completely agree the question and code provided is not consistent so I just gave an example of how to use the callback